# Infusionsoft dataservice.query in Java

Tags: api, infusionsoft

When trying to execute an XML request to Infusionsoft, I cannot get the dataservice.query to function properly. Basically, I have a list of "valid" tags that I would like to find out if a contact has applied to them. In the documentation it says

> queryData: struct (required)
>   A struct containing query data. The key is the field to search on, and the value is the data to look for. % is the wild card operator and all searches are case insensitive. Below is a list of operations you can do.
>
> 1. Greater Than ex: LastUpdated => '~>~ 2017-01-01 00:00:00'
> 2. Greater Than or Equal to ex: LastUpdated => '~>=~ 2017-01-01 00:00:00'
> 3. Less Than ex: LastUpdated => '~<~ 2017-01-01 00:00:00'
> 4. Less Than or Equal to ex: LastUpdated => '~<=~ 2017-01-01 00:00:00'
> 5. Not Equal to ex: Id => '~<>~123'
> 6. Is Null ex: FirstName => '~null~'
> 7. IN statement ex: Id => [1,2,3,4]**
>      *The raw xml, will need be html encoded for '>' and '<'
>      **IN statements only work on Id fields and are limited to 1000 ids

But, I cannot get that in statement to work even through postman...

```
    <member><name>GroupID</name>
      <value><int>in [165,163]</int></value> 
    </member>
```

Obviously that code isn't going to work, but I hope you can see what I am trying to accomplish.

There just isn't clear documentation on how to do this OUTSIDE of PHP SDK.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but the correct formatting should be `[165,163]`. You should **not** include the actual work `in`.

Comment: can you tell me how we can prepare request to search a particular is applied on a contact. i am trying to use DataService.query method of https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-query-a-data-table but i am not sure how to use it.